# Display HTML with qTip2

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, qtip2

I've created a minimized sponsor section with small (50x50 sized) thumbnails through the [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) WordPress plug-in on my site (can be seen [here](http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/)). This plug-in simply displays posts from certain categories anywhere on your website.

I now want to add a tooltip on hovering the image, which would essentially display the posts `the_content();`. For the tooltip I'd be using [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/), since this seems to be the best tooltip solution.

My problem occour, when nothing happens on hovering. Can you spot the error? I've been battling this problem for 3 straight days now.

When looking at the HTML, think as if, you couldn't modify it. The code can be found on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jv8WN/) (I hope the code is valid, but I'm not sure, since this is the first time I'm using JSFIDDLE).

Comment: I personally get errors on your jsFiddle.

Comment: You have any idea how to fix it, @Mark?

Comment: I got a weird error so I didn't dig into it.  If you want to strip down your example on jsFiddle I'll take a look though, you will see the demo's on jsFiddle as well. Ex http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/EEwwg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is your selector for the content of the Qtip. You have `$(this).next('div:hidden')`, but it appears that your text is actually in a `<p>` tag.

EDIT: Just saw the part about not editing the HTML, you'll just have to revise your selector to choose the next `<p>` tag. Something like this `$(this).parent().next('p')[0].textContent`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jv8WN/7/)

EDIT 2: Ideally, I would edit the HTML and do this:

Looking through the [Qtip2 documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/content/), the author offers the solution of putting your desired text content into an attribute of the target element. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jv8WN/3/) is a fiddle demonstrating this.

The relevant HTML:

```
 <a href="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/global-imports-bmw-2/"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/bmw-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-50x50 wp-post-image" alt="DACC Sponsor" qtip-content="Hello, I'm text!"/></a>
```

The qTip code:

```
 $('.lcp_catlist a img').each(function () {
      $(this).qtip({
           content: $(this).next('div:hidden')
      });
  });
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! `$(this).parent().next('p')[0].textContent` works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot use this code any longer. I'm not sure why. Google Chrome returns the error: `Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined` in the console. You know what could have caused this? I've included the latest jQuery, `qtip.js` and `qtip.css` - the same as you used in your Fiddle - but it stills returns with an error, and the tooltip won't display.

Comment: If you can post a link to your fiddle I can help, but without seeing your html source, all I can say is that your selector isn't returning anything, (that's why it is being listed as undefined). I would start there and make sure that you are querying for the right element.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, @Jlange! http://jsfiddle.net/qbR5X/. By the way. What's important to remember is that the content inside of the `<p></p>`'s is from WordPress' `the_content();`. The images are actually posts with a featured image. Just to clarify ;-)

Comment: Ok it looks like you're trying to embed an iFrame within a `<p>` tag. The solution I provided only works if your content is text.

Comment: In order to add the iframe you should try `$(this).parent().next('iframe').html()`, (getting rid of the `<p>` tag all together). After doing this, Qtip throws an error when trying to display the video, so it appears you may be out of luck with this plugin. I would explore creating your own implementation.

Comment: I wish I was able to create my own implementation, but I'm not - unfortunately. Thanks for all your time, @Jlange!